# Hive Case statement date conditions not working

Tags: sql, hive, case

Hi I'm using hive I need to add a case statement with multiple conditions for `jira_label` below.

Basically, if `jira_label` has a null value and the `jira_issue_due_date` is less than the `current date` then the label should be `schedule`. If `jira_label` is just NULL then it needs to be blank `(' ')`.  When I run the below, I'm still getting values that are not showing `Schedule`(348, 351). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, maybe it is the AND condition or order of the statement?

```
SELECT
  jira.issue_id             AS jira_issue_id,
  concat(jira.project_key, '-', CAST(jira.issue_number AS INT)) AS jira_issue_number,
  CASE WHEN jlab.jira_label IS NULL AND jira.issue_due_date_utc < current_timestamp() THEN 'SCHEDULE'
       WHEN jlab.jira_label IS NULL THEN '' ELSE jlab.jira_label END AS jira_label,
  jrel.sow_family           AS sow_family
FROM table
```

Output:

```
jira_label      jira_issue_due_date
348             2022-05-02
349 BUILD       2022-05-02
350 SCHEDULE    2022-05-02
351             2022-05-02
```

Comment: Are `jira.issue_due_date_utc` and `jira_issue_due_date` have same data? Your code has first column but your example has  second one

Comment: yes, the second is just the alias, not sure if this matters?

Comment: Is the data type of `jira_issue_due_date` is `date`? if yes, can you pls use `current_date()` instead of `current_timestamp()`. Because current timestamp has timestamp so it can cause problem. if no, you need to convert it to a date.